# collection.find().property returning undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have the following code:

```
    var permalinkVar = this.params.permalink;
    var imageVar = sites.find({'name':permalinkVar}).createdBy;
    console.log(imageVar);
```

inside a route function, I'm trying to return the `createdBy` property, but im not sure why but it's returning *undefined*. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thas because you are using `.find()` instead of `findOne`

```
var imageVar = sites.findOne({'name':permalinkVar});
console.log(imageVar.createdBy);
```

`.find()` returns the collection instance, where `.createdBy` and `name` doesn't exists.

Comment: That would return:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createdBy' of undefined`

Comment: still getting the same on console :(

Comment: typo on sites? should be Sites? what you get if you print `console.log(permalinkVar)?` and `console.log(imageVar)` `this.params.permalink` whats return? try with `console.log(sites.findOne({name:this.params.permalink})`

Comment: `console.log(permalinkVar)` returns "juego" which is correct
`console.log(imageVar)` returns undefined
`console.log(sites.findOne({'name':this.params.permalink}));` returns undefined

Comment: so, `console.log(Sites.findOne({name:this.params.permalink})` should return and object, also did you have a `waitOn function` and `loading template`? maybe this is happened because the collection isn't ready when you do the find.

Comment: also sites is correct, I'm using it to return `tex:  sites.find({'name':permalinkVar}),` and it's working correctly

Comment: I have a waitOn and laoding template:
`Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});
Router.map(function(){
    this.route('siteform', {path: '/edit'} );
   this.route('site', {
    path: '/:permalink',
    waitOn : function () {
      var permalinkVar = this.params.permalink;
         return [
          Meteor.subscribe('sitios2'),
          Meteor.subscribe('images2'),
         ]
    },`